# Ignore key presses when typing inside of inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, focus, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

I have the following directive that catches certain key presses:

```
angular.module('app').directive('keyPress', function ($document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $document.bind('keyup', function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 83){  // S key
                    element.focus();
                };
                if (e.keyCode == 27){  // ESC key
                    element.blur();
                };
            });
        }
    }
});
```

A search box element then uses it to focus in and out with the `S` and `ESC` key:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" key-press>
```

Unfortunately, when typing into other inputs on the page that includes this search input, the key press is also detected and the search box is focused. Is there a way to only catch key presses when **not** in focus of a different input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting `event.target` you have access to focused element, so you can check if focused element is an input.

```
$document.bind('keyup', function (event) {
    if(event.target.type === 'input') {
        return;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 83){  // S key
        element.focus();
    };
    if (event.keyCode == 27){  // ESC key
        element.blur();
    };
});
```

Comment: Cool, that works! Although, instead of checking if the target type is 'input', it's easier to check if it's null since there are many types of inputs.